# How to get number of days between two java.util.Date variables in scala?

Tags: java, date

I could not find any hand method on `java.util.Date` function in order to get number of days between 2 dates?

How should I get number of days?

Comment: 1/ Don't use `java.util.Date`, it's outdated. Use `java.time` classes. For instance `Instant` could be a good replacement for your use case with an easy way to get the duration between two instances.

Comment: 2/ Is the question about the `Option` wrapper or not? You mention it in the title but then it seems you don't have any issue with it?

Comment: @GaëlJ unfortunately it's a legacy code and API is bound to external clients. So I prefer to use `java.util.Date`

Comment: @GaëlJ I removed Option part so to make the question more clear

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Calculating the difference between two Java date instances](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1555262/calculating-the-difference-between-two-java-date-instances)

Comment: A `Date` represents an instant in time. Two instants could be on the same date in one time zone, and on different dates in another time zone. Do you know which time zone you should use to compute the result?

Comment: Under [the question that @GaëlJ links to](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1555262/calculating-the-difference-between-two-java-date-instances) remember to go for the answers that use java.time, the modern date and time API. There are some.

Comment: Did you remember to search before asking? You forgot to tell us. Similar questions have been asked and answered numerous times.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, convert your legacy `java.util.Date` objects to their modern replacements, `java.time.Instant`. Call new methods added to the old classes.

```
Instant start = myJavaUtilDate.toInstant() ;
```

If by “number of days” you mean “number of 24-hour chunks of time”, without regard for calendar, use `Duration`.

```
long days = Duration.between( start , end ).toDays() ;
```

If you meant calendar days, you need to specify the time zone by which you want to perceive dates.

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "Asia/Tokyo" ) ;
```

Apply that zone to `Instant` to  produce a `ZonedDateTime`. Same moment, same point on the timeline, different wall-clock time and date.

```
ZonedDateTime startZdt = start.atZone( z ) ;
```

Calculate elapsed days using `ChronoUnit` enum `DAYS`.

```
long days = ChronoUnit.between( startZdt , endZdt ) ;
```

Comment: What is `javaUtilDateStart` ?

Comment: @Alireza - `javaUtilDateStart` is any variable referencing an instance of `java.util.Date`. This answer guides you in the right direction. Do not use the error-prone legacy `java.util` date-time API.

Comment: I received `Cannot resolve symbol toInstant()` on my startVariable. If it helps  `public class Date
extends java.util.Date`

Comment: Which Java version are you using? What is the declared type of your `startVariable`?

Comment: @OleV.V. its type is `class Date extends java.util.Date`

Comment: @OleV.V. sorry it was because of `Option[startVariable]` I used map and then turned its value to `toInstant`

Comment: @OleV.V. toInstant returns `throw new java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException()`.  I use `OpenJDK 11`

Comment: While `java.util.Date`and subclass `java.sql.Timestamp`  implement `toInstant`, this is not the case for two other subclasses `java.sql.Date` and `java.sql.Time`. I would expect each of the latter two to throw the exception you mention. So maybe you have got one of those on runtime?

Comment: If your `java.util.Date` are really `java.sql.Date`, cast to the latter type and use its `toLocalDate` method for getting `LocalDate` objects. Then pass two `LocalDate`s to `ChronoUnit.DAYS.between()` to get the difference in dates.